# После обновления jQuery до 1.10.2 перестали работать вкладки Tab

Tags: jquery, javascript

Обновила `jquery-1.8.2.min.js` до `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`.
Все дополнительные скрипты работают вроде бы нормально как и раньше, кроме вкладок Tabs jQuery UI.

```
$(".tabs").tabs();
```

После нажатия на вкладку, открывается ее содержимое и страница сразу перенаправляется на главную сайта. На сайте использую `<base href="http://site.ru/">` для Rewrite ссылок, без него обойтись пока не могу. Если ошибка возникает из-за `base href`, подскажите, как ее вылечить?

Comment: перевод class .tabs в id #tabs тоже не помогает.

Comment: Обновили саму библиотеку - хорошо, но почему б тогда и UI не [обновить][1]?

   [1]:http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Обновила. И сразу во вкладку стала подгружаться главная страница сайта. Помню, раньше тоже возникала такая ошибка, поэтому и откатила версию до "пониже".

Comment: Ок, методом вычислений поняла, что на ошибку влияет все-таки base href.

Тогда встречный вопрос. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обойтись без base href, если при rewrite используются ссылки вида http://site.ru/company/about вместо http://site.ru/head.php?id=company&pa=show&url=about
Соответственно, без base href пути к стилям и ссылки к изображениям в стилях становятся относительно несуществующей папки company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7822

короче говоря формируйте ваши # ссылки базируясь на текущем location.

Comment: В общем, оптимизировала ссылки без учета base href, пришлось попотеть и приписать ко всем ссылкам на сайте слеш /. Как сделать Ваш комментарий ответом?